# how to show process running in cmd with process bar in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

how to show process running in cmd with process bar in C# ?

i tried of using Progress Bar but that is not I really need, I need to just show a process is running in background.

i need to just pop up a bar for cmd process to let user to know that process is running and to have patience.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: i need a bar to pop up when a background process start in cmd in which small green signal moves from left to right repeatedly. Its like signal for the user to wait until process stop.

Comment: Put the ProgressBar in [Marquee](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2xek28f(v=vs.110).aspx) mode: `progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;` "Indicates progress by continuously scrolling a block across a ProgressBar in a marquee fashion."

Comment: yeah great. but how to keep track that the process is running ? means the code..

Comment: Show us the code that launches your process.

Comment: @Idle_Mind We don't even know if he's using `Forms`.  I see `cmd` and it makes me think that it's a `Console` application.